# Spring Boot Application is not Working

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, spring-boot

I am following this wiki to learn [SpringBoot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), whenever i try to run .war file it gave 404 Error.  here are my files which i created on my system.

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <project name="HelloSpringBoot" basedir="." default="usage">
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="test.dir" value="test"/>
    <property name="name" value="HelloSpringBoot"/>

    <path id="master-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <!-- We need the servlet API classes: -->
        <!--  * for Tomcat 5/6 use servlet-api.jar -->
        <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name="servlet*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="usage">
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="${name} build file"/>
        <echo message="-----------------------------------"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="Available targets are:"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="build     --> Build the application"/>
        <echo message="deploy    --> Deploy application as directory"/>
        <echo message="deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file"/>
        <echo message="start-webapp   --> Start application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="stop-webapp    --> Stop application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="deploy-webapp     --> Deploy application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="undeploy-webapp      --> Undeploy application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="list      --> List Tomcat applications"/>
        <echo message=""/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}"  debug="true"
               deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="buildtests" description="Building All TestCases">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true"
               deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
            <src path="${test.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleaning All build files">
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </delete>
    </target>

    <target name="tests" depends="build,buildtests" description="Running All TestCases">
        <junit printsummary="on" fork="false" haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="tests.failed"
               showoutput="true">
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>

            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*Tests.*"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>

        <fail if="tests.failed">
            tests.failed=${tests.failed}
            ***********************************************************
            ***********************************************************
            ****  One or more tests failed!  Check the output ...  ****
            ***********************************************************
            ***********************************************************
        </fail>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Deploy application">
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="deploywar" depends="build" description="Deploy application as a WAR file">
        <war destfile="${name}.war"
             needxmlfile="false">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </war>
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="*.war"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Tomcat tasks - remove these if you don't have Tomcat installed -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->

    <path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
        <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
        <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
            <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
            <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
            <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="catalina-deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    <taskdef name="catalina-list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    <taskdef name="catalina-reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    <taskdef name="catalina-findleaks" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.FindLeaksTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    <taskdef name="catalina-resources" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ResourcesTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    <taskdef name="catalina-start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    <taskdef name="catalina-stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    <taskdef name="catalina-undeploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>

    <target name="start-webapp" description="Start application in Tomcat">
        <catalina-start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                        username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                        path="/${name}" />
    </target>

    <target name="stop-webapp" description="Stop application in Tomcat">
        <catalina-stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="/${name}" />
    </target>

    <target name="deploy-webapp" description="Deploy application in Tomcat">
        <catalina-deploy url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                path="/${name}"
                war="file:${deploy.path}/${name}.war"/>
    </target>

    <target name="undeploy-webapp" description="Undeploy Tomcat application">
        <catalina-undeploy url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
               username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
               password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
               path="/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
        <catalina-list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
              username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
              password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="reload" description="Reload Application in Tomcat">
        <catalina-reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                         username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                         password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                         path="/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- End Tomcat tasks -->

    </project>
```

**Greetings.java**

```
package main.java.POJO;


    public class Greetings {
        private final long id;
        private final String name;

        public Greetings(final long id, final String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public long getId(final long id) {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getName(final long name) {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
```

**GreetingController**

```
package main.java.Controller;

    import main.java.POJO.Greetings;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;



    @RestController
    public class GreetingController {
        private static final String template = "Hello %s";
        private final AtomicLong atomicLong = new AtomicLong();

        @RequestMapping("/greeting")
        public Greetings greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World")String name) {
            return new Greetings(atomicLong.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
        }
    }
```

**Application.Java**

```
package main.java.Application;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"src.main.java.Controller", "src.main.java.POJO"})
    public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

I have all jars of Springframework5.0.2 and SpringBoot-1.5.9 and SpringBoot-AutoConfig-1.5.9, jackson-core and jackson-all , servlet, junit

**Please help me to resolve this issue.**

**EDIT :**
  i run this command on my console :

```
$ ant build deploy deploywar reload
  Buildfile: /Users/Blah/Projects/SpringLearning/HelloSpringBoot/build.xml

 build:
[javac] /Users/Blah/Projects/SpringLearning/HelloSpringBoot/build.xml:46: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/Blah/Projects/SpringLearning/HelloSpringBoot/war/WEB-INF/classes

build:
[javac] /Users/Blah/Projects/SpringLearning/HelloSpringBoot/build.xml:46: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

  deploy:
 [copy] Copying 76 files to /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.5.24/libexec/webapps/HelloSpringBoot

build:
[javac] /Users/Blah/Projects/SpringLearning/HelloSpringBoot/build.xml:46: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

  deploywar:
  [war] Building war: /Users/Blah/Projects/SpringLearning/HelloSpringBoot/HelloSpringBoot.war
 [copy] Copying 1 file to /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.5.24/libexec/webapps
 reload:
 [catalina-reload] OK - Reloaded application at context path [/HelloSpringBoot]
```

Comment: What is the exact URL you are attempting to access? Logs from the console when you start the application would also be revealing. Lastly, as a general tip, it's probably a good idea to learn Maven or Gradle; using Ant for new projects is a pretty bad idea unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for quick reply. I tried these url links till now
http://localhost:8080/greeting
http://localhost:8080/HelloSpringBoot/greeting

Comment: Well i read about ant, and i have an idea what ant is doing, i created other Spring project with same build.xml and it was working fine, so i don't think ant is really any problem here.

Comment: Yeah, without seeing the build and run output from the console, it's hard to know what else is going wrong. One of those two URLs should be correct if the deploy went as planned, because you named the WAR file `HelloSpringBoot.war` and the path you gave in `deploy-war` is `/HelloSpringBoot` (by expanding the property `name` to `HelloSpringBoot`). So the fact that it isn't working is almost certainly going to manifest in an error message on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is designed to run as an executable JAR file (hence the presence of `public static void main(String[] args)`. Spring Boot will then start an embedded web server and handle the rest. If you want to deploy a Spring Boot application, you need to add some supporting classes to make that happen. Check out the instructions [here.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)

Answer (score 0):

`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"src.main.java.Controller", "src.main.java.POJO"})`

base package doesn't look right to me, seems your classes are in:

`package main.java.Controller;` and `package main.java.Application;`.

Is there any reason why you would prefer to maintain a complex `Ant` file and `Spring Boot` dependencies which you would have to also download all the transitive ones instead of using `Maven` or `Graddle`?

Comment: Hey, there isn't any specific reason for ant, i am just learning it.
i tried with different basePackages but still same error.And also i tried to see logs there was no error at all.

Comment: Do you mind using `Maven`, if `Ant` is not a requirement during your learning process?